# How to remove disk password / get to BIOS 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 22.04, password, asus, bios

When I installed Ubuntu, I went with full device encryption.  I’m trying to get to the BIOS, but every time I mash delete, it still brings me to the drive password screen.  After I enter my password, I start mashing delete again, but it takes me to my homepage.  I can’t find anything in the settings to disable the password.  Is there a way that I’m just not getting to get into the BIOS?  If the disk password is the problem, how do I remove it?  I’m running an Asus TUF FX505DT laptop btw

Thank you in advance

Comment: Getting into BIOS is device *firmware* specific, and can require a key to be pressed BEFORE the system starts booting & thus asking for you to enter the encryption key.  As you're getting asked for encryption password, you're not using the correct procedure (*or aren't fast enough*) for your device...  I don't know your device, but I have devices which require me to press & hold keys when off & I get asked if I want to boot external media or go into BIOS/uEFI setup, another requires me to hold key down then press power... ie. *firmware* specific keystrokes where Ubuntu 22.04 isn't involved.

Comment: FYI:   As I have many devices (25+) and it's a royal pain to remember what each needs to enter uEFI/BIOS setup; a fast work around I use is grab a recent Ubuntu *live* ISO (*I have many around so that's easy for me*) & boot that using the procedure that again is device specific... on modern uEFI boxes I get an option to enter uEFI/BIOS Setup at the *live* grub dialog :)   Also I recall some devices have disk passwords (*not part of the OS installed;again device specific password feature*) that require entry before booting; those are device controlled - but very rare.

Answer (score 0):

It’s almost always <kbd>f2</kbd> to enter bios on an Asus laptop.

Other options (apart from <kbd>Del</kbd> which you’ve tried already) - if you can’t find the official documentation - are <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>f10</kbd>, <kbd>f12</kbd>.